# How to upload app with app extension? xcode9

Tags: ios, upload, app-store, itunes

**I have a app and i am using a call directory extension**.
**I don't know how to upload app to Appstore with extension**.

Any one help me with some guidance, video, links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing special to do. If you added the extension with Xcode as target to your project, the extension is uploaded together with the host app.

Comment: Do you have any reference link or video? i want get into deep.

Comment: The Apple documentation tells you anything you need to know: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing.